# Difference in performance between ARM and "traditional" CPU on Raspberry PI example

Tags: performance, cpu, raspberry-pi, arm, cpu-speed

I'm not sure if my question fits here, but I will give it a try since it does not seem to fit any other StackExcnhange.

New day ARM processors are slower (if you look at MHz - 500MHz in RPi case). However they seem to be capable to do alot more things than old 2000MHz Athlon.

I'm runnin an HTPC that runs on old spec Athlon + XBMC. There is no way to play a 720p file not saying about 1020p ones.

However, RPi seems not to have any problem with running movies in FullHD. How is that?

I know you probably can't recalculate ARM MHz into PC MHz. But what's that big difference that PC with 3 times more MHz is not capable of doing something that this small thing can do.

Reason why I ask is because I was thinking about replacing that old PC into RPi, but somehow i cant belive it to the end it can perfrom so much better. I know MHz is not only thing counts, cause CPU's instruction sets also matter. What's that big difference.

Comment: The Raspberry Pi uses a Broadcom BCM2835. It's the integrated graphics coprocessor that enables it to play 1080p. https://www.broadcom.com/products/BCM2835

Comment: So basically It's because it's more like APU? So GPU is doing those calculations instead of CPU?

Comment: Yes. It's like the integrated graphics on an Intel processor or using a graphics card.